# Implementing Google Drive SDK with JavaScript on localhost

Tags: javascript

Hi I’m looking for a simple way to set this up, I am following the Quickstart provided by the Google Developers website and I have created the oAuth to get Client ID and also created the given code example and inserted my Client ID but I ‘m just getting a blank screen.

I’m running it on XAMPP so maybe using localhost for both Redirect URIs and JavaScript Origins may be causing the problem?

At the moment I have ‘localhost/oauth2callback’ for Redirect URI’s and ‘localhost’ for JavaScript Origins. I’m not sure if this is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Make sure you provide some code so you can get more useful and suited answers.

Comment: After quite a bit of research and testing I found an efficient way to do this by using the Zend Framework and especially Zend Gdata to access Google Drive, so I didn’t need to use 0Auth after all.
For anyone who stumbles upon this I would recommend researching Zend_Gdata; you can also run the Zend framework within XAMMP.